# Uploading video to youtube using api's through php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

```
     $httpClient = 
     Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
     $username = '****@gmail.com',
     $password = '*****',
     $service = 'youtube',
     $client = null,
     $source = 'testphp', 
     $loginToken = null,
     $loginCaptcha = null,
     $authenticationURL);
```

I have got the above code from code.google.com. I want to know what `authenticationURL` should be. I new to this help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you copied your code from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#ClientLogin_for_Installed_Applications), then you missed this line:

`$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';`

That's what it is.